# Differentiate the different area paths in Azure Boards under the same Team

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

At the moment, I have one Team with two different area paths defined, however I have issues filtering out the epics and features that are related to one of the area paths since the Filter option does not keep the tree form in its result.

Is there a better way to organize the backlog when I have two different area paths and need easily identify which one a work item belongs to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a better way to organize the backlog when I have two different area paths and need easily identify which one a work item belongs to?

Method 1. Add "Area Path" as a Column.

Click Column Options at the top and Add "Area Path" as a clumn. Then you can see area directly at the page.

Method 2. Use queries.

Go to Boards/Queries. Create a query and set your Work Item Type and your Area path. Here is an example.

[image]

Then select "Tree of work items" in "Type of query".

[image]

You will find work items in a specific area arranged in a tree form.

Answer (score 0):

One way to filter is by specifying an area path in the filter text area like:

[image]

Note that it does not work with the Kanban board.